# How to change In Stock text into in stock in WooCommerce Product Edit Admin End

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change **In Stock** label into **in stock** in product edit inventory section on admin section. I have used following code but its changing the text on front end not changing on back-end i want to change the label on back-end not in front end. I have attached the screenshot of where i want to change the text.

Screen Shot : https://prnt.sc/obz1uc

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('in stock', 'woocommerce');

}
```

Could you please help me to solve the issue,
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function custom_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'In Stock' :
            $translated_text = 'in stock';
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Let me know if it does the job and good luck ;)

PS. you could add an additional check on the $domain var to make sure to target on WooCommerce text.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Cheers!